# Remote Desktop not showing up as an option?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, vmware-fusion

I installed Windows XP using VMWare Fusion on a mac. I want to but cannot remote desktop to that VM because when VMWAre Fusion did the auto-install of Windows XP, it did not enable remote desktop. It is the Professional version of Windows XP, so remote desktop is possible (and in fact, if I install it from scratch, the remote desktop option is there).

Another way of saying this is that there is no Remote tab showing up when I right-click on my computer: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/mobility/getstarted/enableremote.mspx

Anyone know how to enable remote desktop if it wasnt configured when windows was installed?

Answer (score 2):

To restore the tab, follow these steps:

Click Start, Run and type this command:

```
regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\remotepg.dll
```

If you receive an error stating that the module could not be found, or stating no registration helper is registered for this file type (which indicates a corrupt DLL), extracting a new copy from XP CD should help. Make sure that you extract the updated copy of the DLL file if you have applied the XP Service Pack in your system. Register the DLL again.

(Extract the DLL from a Slipstreamed XP CD, or copy the remotepg.dll from ServicePackFiles\i386 folder to Windows\System32 folder)

To extract the DLL from Windows XP CD, type this in Command Prompt

```
EXPAND X:\I386\REMOTEPG.DL_ -R C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32
```

Where X:\ is your CD-ROM drive letter. The above command assumes Windows is installed in C:\ drive. If not, change the drive letter / Path accordingly.

[Source](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/remotetab.htm)